# VSCode , cmake debug is not providing output on Windows PC

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, cmake, vscode-debugger

I have configured my vscode with CMake the program gives output in the terminal but when debugging there is no output observed. Could someone suggest where can be a possible mistake? [image: Debug Image]

The code runs in vscode with CMake it only doesn't provide a debug output console like no output in terminal or debug console

[image: Built executing image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `"externalConsole": true` to `settings.json`:

```json
"cmake.debugConfig": {
        "externalConsole": true,
    },
```

[image]

After that, you will see the output info in the terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @yushulx works but will always open a new terminal. If you want to have the output in the integrated terminal of vscode you can use the option

```json
"cmake.debugConfig": {
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```